# Java - Get list network interface in Linux

Tags: java

How can I get all network interface in Linux using Java.
I used Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Because when I develop on my Windows 10 Machine, everything is look good.
`[10.60.36.61, 127.0.0.1]`

Here is the source code.
Any help it so appreciated.

**IPValidator.java**

```
package helper;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class IpValidator {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN
            = "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

    public IpValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    }

    /**
     * Validate ip address with regular expression
     *
     * @param ip ip address for validation
     * @return true valid ip address, false invalid ip address
     */
    public boolean validate(final String ip) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;


ArrayList<Object> ipAddresess = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

    //Lopping all 
    IpValidator ipValidator = new IpValidator();


    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {

        NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();

        // drop inactive
        if (!networkInterface.isUp()) {
            continue;
        }

        // Explore Inet Address
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();

        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
            boolean matches = ipValidator.validate(addr.getHostAddress());

            if (matches) {
                ipAddresess.add(addr.getHostAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.reverse(ipAddresess);
    jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ipAddresess.toArray()));

} catch (SocketException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
}

System.out.println(ipAddresess);
```

Comment: Aside from your question: 1) don't make `matcher` a field in your class, make it a local variable instead. As it stands, you have a thread interference problem. 2) no need to keep compiling the pattern, make `pattern` static.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, your Linux machine has IPv6 addresses, which wouldn't match your regex. You can test this by logging or printing addresses when you reject them.

**I also don't understand why you're using a regex in the first place.** Unless Java really screws up, anything returned by the `getHostAddress` method will be a valid IP address. So why validate it with a regex?

Anyway, if you find that `getInetAddresses` is returning IPv4 addresses on your Linux machine, then please log the addresses that are getting rejected and post the results with your question.

Comment: Oke, my mistake in code. LInux Ubuntu 18.04 doesn`t support tray icon (another part of my code)i before those line is execute.